# Spacy lemmatization: Incorrect results for the word "number"

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, spacy, lemmatization

I found that spacy incorrectly lemmatizes the word "number" to "numb", and this results in inaccurate topics when I do the topic modeling afterwards. Below is a sample code with the output "numb". I tried to replace "word.lemma_" with "word.lemma_.strip()" but got the same results.

How do I customize the lemma_ function so that "number" won't be transformed to "numb" after lemmatization?

```
test = nlp('number')

for word in test:
        print(word.lemma_)

##This output "numb"
```

Update:
I tried to force the POS of 'number' to NOUN, but still get 'numb' after the .lemma_ function.

```
from spacy.symbols import NOUN, PROPN

test = nlp('my phone number is 3')

for word in test:
    if word.text == "number":
        word.pos = NOUN
    
    print(word.lemma_)
```

Comment: This works correctly for me and gives a lemma of "number".  The issue is probably because it's not recognizing your word as a noun.  You can see this is you print word.pos_.  Generally, lemmatization requires the part-of-speech, and POS tags often don't get assigned correctly unless you use full sentences.

Comment: which model are you using.

Comment: The sentence is "My phone number is xxxx", but "number" still gets lemmatized to "numb" after using word.lemma_ .

Comment: Please see the edited post. I transformed the POS to NOUN, but still get "numb" after .lemma_ transformation. Could you please let me know how you get the correct result?